# Запись в файл хеш пароля + IV и Salt

Tags: c#, aes

Какое на данный момент лучше средство для хеширования пароля с записью Salt + IV + Пароль шифрованный файл  ?

Comment: Я же кидал ссылку под прошлым вашим вопросом на пример. А так, хэш не надо шифровать, из хэша невозможно восстановить исходный пароль.

Comment: @aepot, а я и не собираюсь сам хэш шифровать, тип string в hash, затем сохранить его в файл и как-нибудь проверить что-ли, но, я понял что обратно уже не получиться сравнить с паролем. Вот думаю что лучше наверное использовать `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, кстати в студии не позволяет увидеть 4 аргумент `HashAlgorithmName.SHA256` в `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` мб это в Net.Core только ?  
Меня интересует вопрос, если я генерирую соль и вектор случайно и хочу записать в файл, то как потом проверить правильность соли на корректность ? Или её просто читать без проверки нужно ?

Comment: Вектор передавайте вместе с данными как префикс или суффикс, его же можете и как соль использовать, ровно так как я показывал в примере. SHA256 не критично, там по умолчанию SHA1, его вполне достаточно. Правильность соли? Соль - это такой же рандом, как и вектор, как соль может быть некорректной? Если пароль+соль дают правильный хэш, значит все ок, если же нет, то либо то неверно, либо другое. Соль нужна, чтобы сделать бессмысленной атаку по словарю, то есть восстановить пароль по хэшу, больше ни для чего, в ней нет ничего секретного, как и в IV.